# youtube autoplay is not working

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I am using youtube embed  to display a video. I need to autoplay when site is opened

```
<iframe class="slider-image-mockup align-center" width="100%" height="750" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/Y-p828Jy8C8?rel=0&amp;controls=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=Y-p828Jy8C8&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; loop; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I am using this code before it was working fine but for past few days. Autoplay is not working...

It may sound crazy but I didn't change anything in my code.
its showing like below after clicking of play button only video is playing

[image]

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: **is not working...** is not sufficient info. What error are you getting? Share more info

Comment: Chrome but thats not a matter evan in opera and mozila also not working

Comment: vicJordan i have edited my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: no its not working as expected... in your code also after clicking the play only video is playing

Comment: @ShazvanHanif please copy this code and create new file and run your pc this is working for me

Comment: which browser you are using

Comment: but now I have changed the url

from : https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/Y-p828Jy8C8?rel=0&controls=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=Y-p828Jy8C8&showinfo=0

To : https://www.youtube.com/embed/Y-p828Jy8C8?rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=Y-p828Jy8C8

now its working... Thank you..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172945/discussion-between-nikunj-kathrotiya-and-shazvan-hanif).

Answer (score 1):

now I have changed the url

from : https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/Y-p828Jy8C8?rel=0&controls=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=Y-p828Jy8C8&showinfo=0

To : https://www.youtube.com/embed/Y-p828Jy8C8?rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=Y-p828Jy8C8

now its working... Thank you..